# openni_tracker on ubuntu11.10 on VMware

Tags: openni, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm very new to linux and ros. I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on VMware. I have installed ROS following guide from here "http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu" and openni_kinect from here "http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect".
Now when I run "roscore" on one terminal (it runs successfully) and "rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker" on other terminal, nothing is happening (even when I stand in front of sensor). When I run "rosnode list" on third terminal, there is "/openni_tracker" node added to the list. When I run "rostopic list" there is no new topics. After a while of nothingness, an error appears and it stops. The error is:
"[ERROR] [1336588766.792536891]: InitFromXml failed: Xiron OS got an event timeout!"
The "/openni_tracker" node is gone after that. Each time I try to run it again, I get error almost immediately. Error is:
"[ERROR] [1337177233.598450808]: InitFromXml failed: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!".  The "/openni_tracker" node is also created for a short period.

Also if I would try to launch other things, if something wouldn't work, it would be because some sort of timeout error so I guess it's the same problem.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34132/openni_tracker-on-ubuntu11.10-on-vmware/) by [nnyJoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2391/nnyjoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

The Kinect device does not seem to work in a VM. The only solution I know is to dual boot Ubuntu.

Best regards.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0